For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, prove: if $x^2 \geq x$, then $x \leq 0$ or $x \geq 1$.
Here's the problem: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x^2 \geq x$, then $x \leq 0$ or $x \geq 1$.
Here are is one related question and another. The latter is a question about a more general case and the former is an attempt using proof by contradiction, which is different from my approach here.

Here's my proof:
Let $x_{0}$ be a fixed, but arbitrary, real number. By the contrapositive, assume $0<x_{0}<1$; we must prove $x_{0}^{2}<x_{0}$. From our assumption, we see $x_0 > 0$, so multiplying both sides of the inequality by $x_0$ will not change the sign. Thus, we have $x_0^2 < x_0$, as desired.

I don't see any obvious issues with this approach, but, for whatever reason, alarm bells are ringing in my head, as if I am missing something. Are these concerns unfounded? Is my proof sound?

Looks fine. This is the usual proof.

@Malady Oh, awesome! Thanks.

That shows that $x_0^2$ is positive but not that $x_0^2 < 1$.

Maybe I'm not sure what you mean be "multiplying both sides of the inequality".  Which inequality?  The way to do it is to use the axiom:  If $a<b$ and $c > 1$ then $ac<bc$.  So if $0 < x_0 < 1$ then $x_0 < 1$ and $x_0 > 0$ so $x_0\times x_0 < 1\times x_0$.  Is that what you are trying to say?

Alternative.  If $x^2\ge x$ and $x > 0$ then $\frac 1x > 0$ so $\frac {x^2}x \ge \frac xx$ or $x \ge 1$.  So if $x^2 \ge x$ then either $x>0$ and  $x \ge 1$; or $x \le 0$.

@fleablood to me it was clear. Our OP took the inequality $x_0<1$ and by the positivity of $x_0$ concluded that $x_0^2<x_0$

@fleablood I think I see what you mean. Would "...assume $0<x_{0}$ and $x_{0}<1$..." and "...multiplying both sides of the latter inequality..." clarify the wording? I also appreciate your alternative; I had a similar idea, but I wasn't sure how to proceed.

@Malady "to me it was clear".  You are probably right but to me it wasn't clear what was being said and I did actually miss the point.  In any event... saying that $x_0 < 1$ and $x_0$ is positive and therefore $x_0\cdot x_0 < 1\cdot x_0$ is certainly a correct way to prove it. If this is what the OP was doing (and it seems they were) then they have done it perfectly correctly.  (It's a personal preference of mine that the steps of a proof be explicitely stated. Or course the other side of a coin is a proof shouldn't be verbose over trivialities so.... everyone's milage may vary.)
